# docker on centos that has no internet, rpm package dependency issue

Tags: docker, centos

I am facing an issue installing docker-ce from package on a server that has no internet access.

This is the version of my Linux | centos-release-7-2.1511.el7.centos.2.10.x86_64

```
Virtualization: vmware
Operating system: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
Architecture: x86-64
```

Im trying to follow the instructions as set here however since the box doesnt have internet I can't do the yum install.

So I was doing it with `rpm -ivh`. So far im getting dependency errors after dependency errors.

I tried these 3 versions of docker and all of them are giving out a dependency errors.

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 19521288 Nov 8 00:52 docker-ce-17.03.0.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 19529520 Nov 8 00:02 docker-ce-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 29108 Nov 8 00:53 docker-ce-selinux-17.03.0.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 29108 Nov 8 00:03 docker-ce-selinux-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 19509116 Nov 8 01:26 docker-engine-1.13.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 29024 Nov 8 01:26 docker-engine-selinux-1.13.1-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm

rpm -ivh /docker/images/docker-ce-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
warning: /docker/images/docker-ce-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID 621e9f35: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
docker-ce-selinux >= 17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos is needed by docker-ce-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64

rpm -ivh /docker/images/docker-ce-selinux-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
warning: /docker/images/docker-ce-selinux-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID 621e9f35: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
selinux-policy-base >= 3.13.1-102 is needed by docker-ce-selinux-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch
selinux-policy-targeted >= 3.13.1-102 is needed by docker-ce-selinux-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch
```

So I tried looking for that selinux package the I found on the site below:

I tried installing the rpm from rpmfindand unfortunately, its asking for another dependency.

```
rpm -ivh selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-102.el7.noarch.rpm
warning: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-102.el7.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
policycoreutils-python >= 2.5 is needed by selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-102.el7.noarch
selinux-policy = 3.13.1-102.el7 is needed by selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-102.el7.noarch

rpm -ivh selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-102.el7.noarch.rpm
warning: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-102.el7.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
policycoreutils >= 2.5 is needed by selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-102.el7.noarch
selinux-policy = 3.13.1-102.el7 is needed by selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-102.el7.noarch
```

Has anyone tried installing docker on this version of centos before that has no access to the internet?
Do you have any easier way of getting through this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On a machine with internet, download all dependencies:

```
mkdir -p offline_repo && cd offline_repo
curl -O https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
curl -O https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-selinux-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=. docker-ce-*.rpm
```

You can do it on any machine (any OS) that have docker installed and internet access, you can download the dependencies within a container:

```
mkdir offline_repo
docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/offline_repo:/offline_repo centos:7.2.1511 \
  sh -c 'cd /offline_repo \
      && curl -O https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm \
      && curl -O https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-selinux-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm \
      && yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=. docker-ce-*.rpm'
```

Now you should have all required packages available in the `offline_repo` dir, which should look like this:

```
$ ls -1 offline_repo/
audit-libs-2.6.5-3.el7_3.1.x86_64.rpm
audit-libs-python-2.6.5-3.el7_3.1.x86_64.rpm
checkpolicy-2.5-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
docker-ce-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
docker-ce-selinux-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
iptables-1.4.21-17.el7.x86_64.rpm
libcgroup-0.41-11.el7.x86_64.rpm
libmnl-1.0.3-7.el7.x86_64.rpm
libnetfilter_conntrack-1.0.6-1.el7_3.x86_64.rpm
libnfnetlink-1.0.1-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
libseccomp-2.3.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
libselinux-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm
libselinux-python-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm
libselinux-utils-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm
libsemanage-2.5-5.1.el7_3.x86_64.rpm
libsemanage-python-2.5-5.1.el7_3.x86_64.rpm
libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm
libtool-ltdl-2.4.2-22.el7_3.x86_64.rpm
policycoreutils-2.5-11.el7_3.x86_64.rpm
policycoreutils-python-2.5-11.el7_3.x86_64.rpm
python-IPy-0.75-6.el7.noarch.rpm
selinux-policy-3.13.1-102.el7_3.16.noarch.rpm
selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-102.el7_3.16.noarch.rpm
selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-102.el7_3.16.noarch.rpm
setools-libs-3.3.8-1.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
systemd-219-30.el7_3.9.x86_64.rpm
systemd-libs-219-30.el7_3.9.x86_64.rpm
```

Then simply copy it to the offline machine, then install all packages:

```
cd offline_repo
yum install -y --cacheonly --disablerepo=* *.rpm
```

Comment: very practical! saved my ass today.